# jQuery smooth scroll to a div using animate

Tags: jquery

**Overview:**
I am using anchor tags to scroll to their respective divs as assigned in href.

**HTML Markup:**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#howToUse">How to use</a></li>
    <li><a href="#benefits">Benefits</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="howToUse">
     Some content
</div>

<div id="benefits">
     Some content
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('ul.nav').find('a').click(function(){
    var $href = $(this).attr('href');
    var $anchor = $('#'+$href).offset();
    $('body').animate({ scrollTop: $anchor.top },'slow');
    return false;
});
```

**Problem:**
So, now when I click on the anchor tag the window scrolls to the particular div but the scroll is not smooth or slow. I would rather say it is not scrolling at all. It just jumps to that div.

I have used animate and also used the parameter slow with it. So, what is my mistake here? How can I achieve the smooth scroll that I am lookin for here.

*Website*:

http://irankmedia.com/uskincare/

Hi there please check the navigation bar in this website which doesn't give me the smooth scroll effect I am expecting.

Hope it will bring a clear idea.

Comment: try `$('ul.nav').find('a').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();`

Comment: @Kiran Kumar Dash Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ##howToUse would be there that is due to $('#'+ $href)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `$('#'+ $href).offset();`, since the `href` itself has `#`, it throws an error like `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ##howToUse`

```
$('ul.nav').find('a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    var $anchor = $(target).offset();
    $('body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $anchor.top
    }, 'slow');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dctnbo8c/)

Comment: In my case it just jumps to the div instead of scrolling. my problem is that it doesn't scroll smoothly.so, what could be the reason?

Comment: @KiranKumarDash since there is a script error, the animation code is not getting executed... so the default action of the anchor click is happening - the problem is https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dctnbo8c/

Comment: Yes I have seen the solution but just doesn't work in my case

Comment: @KiranKumarDash then try to recreate the bug in the fiddle... else there is not much we can do

Comment: This is the website where I am trying it: irankmedia.com/uskincare

Comment: @KiranKumarDash in your html you are missing `</script>` after `<script src="js/my.js"></script>` so (`<script src="js/my.js"></script>`) - also it is a good idea to use dom ready handler in your script

Answer (score 3):

Just **remove the '#' used with $href**  otherwise your code is working fine dude

```
$('ul.nav').find('a').click(function(){
    var $href = $(this).attr('href');
    var $anchor = $($href).offset();
    $('body').animate({ 
          scrollTop: $anchor.top 
    },'slow');
    return false;
});
```

it's throwing Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ##howToUse

Comment: thanks. but still the scroll is not smooth. It just jumps to the div. I am expecting it to scroll smoothly.

Comment: @Kiran Kumar Dash you can change the 'slow' to particular mileseconds like 1000 or as per your need refer **http://api.jquery.com/animate/  ** for how to apply animation speed

Comment: This is the website where I am trying it: irankmedia.com/uskincare

Comment: @Kiran Kumar Dash i can't access it due to some reasons why don't you create jsfiddle .? so that i can help you

Comment: I did solve it friend. thank you. it was just a silly mistake. I missed a tag.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('ul.nav').find('a').click(function() {
    var $href = $(this).attr('href');
    //var $anchor = $('#'+$href).offset();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($href).offset().top
    }, 2000);
    return false;
});
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gfaohx9g/)

Comment: Still could not solve my issue. It just jumps to the div. I am expecting it to scroll smoothly.

Comment: I have seen your code. So, I know the code is correct. But in my case it just jumps to the div.

Comment: Yes. I have seen your demo. that's right. But what could be the reason that in my case it is unable to scroll smoothly.

Comment: You definately have a reference to jQuery on your page? For example: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yes I do have jquery cdn url

Comment: Can you confirm that jQuery is running correctly? If you add an alert(1); at the top of your anchor click event does it fire? What you are seeing would suggest that jQuery is not working.